# tensorflow multi diemensional indexing

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have

- 4 dimensional float tensor `y` and
- 3 dimensional integer tensor `y_index`, containing the index of the 4th dimension of the y to extract

What I want to do is pretty simple with 3 for-loop with numpy:

```
y = np.random.randint(100,size=(5,10,20,3))
y_index= np.random.randint(3,size=(5,10,20))
y_slice = np.zeros_like(y_index)
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y.shape[1]):
        for k in range(y.shape[2]):
            y_slice[i,j,k] = y[i,j,k,y_index[i,j,k]]
y_slice
```

How can I do this efficiently in tensorflow? I am guessnig that I need to use tf.gether_nd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. Basically, first you flatten the all dimensions except last of `y` and create an index for the flatten `y`. You do the indexing and then reshape to the correct shape.

```
y = tf.constant(np.random.normal(size=(5,10,20,3)), dtype='float32')
y_index = tf.constant(np.random.randint(3, size=(5,10,20)), dtype='int32')
# Creating an index like [(0,y_index[0]), (1, y_index[1]), ...]
inds = tf.stack([tf.range(5*10*20),tf.reshape(y_index,[-1])],axis=1)

y_slice = tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(tf.reshape(y,[-1,3]),inds),[5,10,20])
```

Comment: Thank you. do you have any suggestion if the first dimension is None? i.e. (None,10,20,3)